# get bass from audio using java script

Tags: javascript, audio, get, bass

how to get bass from audio using java script?
is it possible using **javascript** or **jQuery**?
I want to get it and put it in a variable like this:

```
<audio src="X.mp3" autoplay style="display:none;" ></audio>
```

is there any scirpt code to get the bass and treble from this audio every secondes and put it in a variable?

Comment: Not seeing any reason for close votes here. The OP is asking if there's some kind of API to the audio data and/or mixer/equalizer for the output. There's so much going on with JavaScript APIs these days it's entirely possible. (I don't *think* there is, but it's a reasonable question.)

Comment: @ mahdi: Do you want to extract the "bass" in some way, or are you looking for control over the equalization of the playback? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: no I only want to take it and put it in a variable ,and for example write it in my web page

Comment: That's still really unclear. Do you mean you want to take only the "bass" part of the audio data and put it in an array? Or what? In general, the more detail and specifics you put into your question, the better the answers. Effort yields rewards.

Comment: i want to extract the bass in some way /sorry if i can,t describe very well

Comment: in an array or variable\

Comment: Please check [`Web Audio API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API) at MDN.

Comment: Do you want the value so you can, eg, draw a meter, or do you want the raw value so you can, eg, play the sound but with only the bass?